# Python urllib3 Lambda: LocationValueError: No host specified HTTP Webhook

Tags: python, http, lambda, webhooks, urllib3

I'm using urllib3 library and python3 lambda code that fetches the webhook url of MSTeams from AWS Secret Manager and sends a `http post` request to publish a SNS message.

My  `webhook url` stars with https a d looks like this "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/.......". On executing the lambda function, I get an error as shown below for `LocationValueError: No host specified`

Code

```
import urllib3 

http = urllib3.PoolManager() 

MSTEAMS_WEBHOOK_SECRET_NAME = os.getenv('MSTEAMS_WEBHOOK_SECRET_NAME') 
HOOK_URL = get_secret(MSTEAMS_WEBHOOK_SECRET_NAME) 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 message = {
      "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
      "@type": "MessageCard",
      "themeColor": data["colour"],
      "title": title,
      "text": "accountId:\n"  + account_id + " <br/>\n" 
    }
 
    webhook_encoded_body = json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')
    response = http.request('POST',HOOK_URL, body=webhook_encoded_body)
```

**Error while testing on Python 3.7 lambda execution engine **

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 145, in lambda_handler
    resp = http.request('POST',HOOK_URL, body=webhook_encoded_body)
  File "/var/runtime/urllib3/request.py", line 80, in request
    method, url, fields=fields, headers=headers, **urlopen_kw
  File "/var/runtime/urllib3/request.py", line 171, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/var/runtime/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 325, in urlopen
    conn = self.connection_from_host(u.host, port=u.port, scheme=u.scheme)
  File "/var/runtime/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 231, in connection_from_host
    raise LocationValueError("No host specified.")```

References
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-lambda-webhooks-chime-slack-teams/
````

Comment: Check `HOOK_URL` see what's returned from `get_secret()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173904/python-errorno-host-specified

Comment: @Frank I habe bypassed this error and now getting a Location Parse error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64742206/python-urllib3-lambda-error-locationparseerror-failed-to-parse